# Fire an event after .css() is invoked (saving current style)?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, callback

**The situation**: my jQuery plugin allows me to pass a function to be executed if returned object (from ajax call) contains an error property. In that function one can set `css()` properties to highlight the fail. In the code parameter `isError` is used to simulate this.

**The problem**: When the plugin is invoked *two consecutive times* and there is a *success after an error*, of course the style is unchanged and `$(this).html("Success")` shows a *creepy red text*.

**The question**: is there any way to execute an event after `.css()` is invoked thus saving the current style for restore it later (only on success)?

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
      $('#container').attach({}, true);  // First call is error
      $('#container').attach({}, false); // Second call is success
</script>
```

This is (part of) my plugin:

```
(function($) {
   $.fn.attach = function(options, isError) {

      var opt = $.extend({
         onError : function(message) { // Default function for errors
            this.html('Error: ' + message + '.').css('color', 'red');
        }
      }, options);

      // Loop each selection item
      this.each(function() {

         if(isError) // An error occurred, call opt.onError
         {
            opt.onError.call($(this), "Message");
            return true; // End of the current element process
         }

         $(this).html("Success"); // No errors, set success text

      });

   };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Don't set the style with JS, set the a class with JS, and set the style with actual CSS.

Comment: Could you make an additional jquery plugin that is essentially a modified `.css()` method that does what you want it to? then you'd just call this modified method instead.

Comment: @zzzzBov and maxedison both your solutions seems interesting...

Comment: No additional plugin needed, just wrap and replace `css` inside the current plugin. Should be pretty straightforward. But there might be a better way to deal with the whole situation.

Comment: @FelixKling can you be more specific? Where .css function should be placed?

Comment: Just where you defined `$.fn.attach` as well. But after thinking about it, in my opinion it would be cleaner if you let the user define an `onSuccess` callback as well, and instead of using `css`, let the user defined two classes for the success and error case and set them on the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But after thinking about it, in my opinion a cleaner approach would be to let the user define an `onSuccess` callback as well, and instead of using .`css`, let the user defined two classes for the success and error case and set them on the element.

Example:

```
(function($) {
   $.fn.attach = function(options, isError) {

      var opt = $.extend({
         onError : function(message) { // Default function for errors
            $(this).html('Error: ' + message + '.');
        },
        onSuccess: function(message) {
            $(this).html('Success');
        },
        errorClass: 'error',
        successClass: 'success'
      }, options);

      // Loop each selection item
      this.each(function() {

         var method = 'onSuccess',
             cssClass = 'successClass';


         if(isError) // An error occurred, call opt.onError
         {
            method = 'onError';
            cssClass = 'errorClass';
            return true; // End of the current element process
         }

         opt[method].call(this, 'Message');
         $(this).removeClass(cssClass === 'successClass' ? opt.errorClass : opt.successClass)
                .addClass(opt[cssClass]);    
      });
   };
})(jQuery);
```

Note that I also change `call($(this),...)` to `call(this, ...)` so that the callbacks behave the same way as traditional callbacks.

---

Nevertheless, to answer the question stated: To let `css` trigger an event, you can wrap the function like so:

```js
(function($) {
    var orig_css = $.fn.css;
    $.fn.css = function() {
        var result = orig_css.apply(this, arguments);
        if(arguments.length === 2) { // CSS property was set
            $(this).trigger('css_changed'); // or whatever event you want to trigger
        }
        return result;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8WyNp/)

Comment: Sorry, for the sake of simplicity i omitted that that plugin selection is populated with data coming from the server, so success can't be passed to the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

A different and simpler route might be to work with classes and *not* store the old class.  when there's an error, assign the error class.  Use `.addClass()` to mark the error state, and on success, use `.removeClass` to remove an error class if present.  If it's not present, jQuery just moves on without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a wrapper function for `.css()` that does this.

Your function, `.mycss()`, would be pretty simple.  You take the style that you want to set as a parameter, just like `.css()`.  You record the current CSS with `.data()` so you can retrieve it later.  Then you use `.css()` as normal to set the style you want.

You can make a second `.resetcss()` function to check for data associated with the selected element and set that data as your CSS.  Or you could roll this functionality into `.mycss()` so it stores/sets CSS if you pass a style parameter and restores CSS if you send it without a parameter.

Your exact needs may be a little different, but you can modify the function(s) to meet those needs.  You may want to check for stored style data before you set new data and decide if you revert to the old style or use the new one.  Alternately, if you go with CSS classes (a good choice) you could make a `.myclass()` function instead that stores your previous class and sets a new class, allowing you to retrieve that later instead.

Comment: This sounds good but it will force plugin users to remember to use `.mycss()` instead...